# My Rails Controller Spec is Not Passing When a Redirect Happens

Tags: rspec-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm using `rails 6` and `ruby 3.1.1` and `Rspec`

It's been a minute since I've written tests, so the syntax is a bit new to me, but "I think" I understand it. A controller `create` test is not passing. It creates a new badge, then redirects to the badge show page. "I think" it is failing on the redirect. Debug code shows the record is saved, and a `redirect_to` is the next line.

I do not know what I need to change to make this work.  Help?

```
# my app/controller

def create
  badge = LivingMuayThai::Badge.new(badge_params)
  if badge.save
    logger.info("@@@@@@@@@@@ badge controller create") # for debugging in test
    flash[:notice] = "You created a new Badge record"
    redirect_to(living_muay_thai_badge_path :id => badge.id)
  else
    flash[:notice] = "Creating that Badge did not work. hmmm!"
    render "new"
  end
end
```

```
# my controller spec

require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe LivingMuayThai::BadgesController, type: :controller do

  let(:valid_attributes) do
    {
     'badge_name'  => 'boxing 4 silver',
     'category'    => 'boxing',
     'color'       => 'silver',
     'number'      => 4,
     'image_name'  => 'boxing-4-silver.png',
     'sort_order'  => 4
    }
   end

  describe 'POST /create' do
    context 'with valid parameters' do
      it 'redirects to show badge' do
        post :create, params: { living_muay_thai_badge: valid_attributes }
        expect(response).to be_successful
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Failures:
  1) LivingMuayThai::BadgesController POST /create with valid parameters redirects to show badge
     Failure/Error: expect(response).to be_successful
       expected `#<ActionDispatch::TestResponse:0x00007fccb41e3268 @mon_data=#<Monitor:0x00007fccb41e31f0>, 
@mon_data_...equest=#<ActionController::TestRequest 
POST "http://test.host/living_muay_thai/badges" for 0.0.0.0>>.successful?` to be truthy, got false

     # ./spec/controllers/living_muay_thai/badges_controller_spec.rb:80:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

When I, `tail -f log/test.log`, I see the `logger.info` line I put in the `app/controller`, so I know the `if badge.save` is working. That makes me think something is happening on the redirect.

Am I missing something really obvious? Something in the syntax or structure of the test?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I sort stumbled onto the answer.  I was trying anything I could to get this to work and I just added `.to be_redirect` and it worked.

```
expect(response).to be_redirect
```

Hope this helps others.